# Trouble with ImportHTML

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to use `=IMPORTHTML` and am having trouble making it work.
Here is what I have so far

```
=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_mid,fa_curratio_o1,fa_pe_u15,fa_roe_o20,fa_roi_o15&ft=2","table",15),3,3)
```

I am sure about the table number, but I keep getting errors saying that my index values are invalid because they should be between 1 and 0 which doesn't make sense to me.

Furthermore, I am looking to import the whole table and if I only use the `=IMPORTHTML` it says I need the `=INDEX` function. Is there a way to import the whole thing or do I have to do it manually?

Comment: what exactly you want to import over?

Comment: The most important would be the ticker, the sector, industry, market cap and P/E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=QUERY(IMPORTHTML(
 "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_mid,fa_
  curratio_o1,fa_pe_u15,fa_roe_o20,fa_roi_o15&ft=2",
 "table", 13), "Select Col2, Col4, Col5, Col7, Col8")
```

[image]

Comment: How did you find that it was table 13 and not 15? Trial and error? or is there another way?
Thanks in any case!